# Train Ticket Machine in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am new in VHDL. I try to create train ticket machine using vhdl. It have 3 destination and all destination have fee. When user insert money with same of fee, ticket will out and no change but if user enter extra money than fee, ticket will out also with change.When i run the simulation all output does not appear correctly but only come out with uuu. Anybody can help me with my code below, please.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;  
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity trainticket_machine is

PORT( Clock,Reset,Cancel                            :  IN STD_LOGIC;
        RM1,RM2,RM5                                     : IN STD_LOGIC;
        KL_station,Mid_station,Klang_station    : IN STD_LOGIC;
        Ticket                                          : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        Change,Retrn                                : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
        Money_sum                                       : INOUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0)
        );
end trainticket_machine;

architecture Behavioral of trainticket_machine is

        TYPE state IS (S0,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,Cancl,waiting1,waiting2,waiting3,KL_Ticket,Mid_Ticket,Shah_Ticket);
        SIGNAL p_state,Train_state: STATE;
BEGIN

PROCESS(Reset,Clock)

BEGIN

IF (Reset = '1') THEN
    p_state <= S0;
    Ticket <= '0';
    Retrn <= "0000";
    Money_sum <= "ZZZZ";
ELSIF   (Clock'EVENT AND Clock = '1') THEN 
 p_state <= Train_state;
END IF;
END PROCESS;

PROCESS (p_state,Cancel,RM1,RM2,RM5,KL_station,Mid_station,Klang_station)    
BEGIN   
CASE p_state IS

    WHEN S0 =>

        Money_sum <= "0000";
        Change <= "0000";

        IF   (KL_station = '1') THEN Train_state <= waiting1;
        ELSIF(Mid_station = '1') THEN Train_state <= waiting2;
        ELSIF(Klang_station = '1') THEN Train_state <= waiting3;
        ELSE Train_state <= S0;
        END IF;

    WHEN waiting1 =>

        Ticket <= '0';
        Change <= "0000";

        IF     (RM1 = '1') THEN Train_state <= S1;
        ELSIF  (RM2 = '1') THEN Train_state <= S2;
        ELSIF  (RM5 = '1') THEN Train_state <= S3;
        ELSIF    (Money_sum >= 2) THEN train_state <= KL_Ticket;
        ELSIF  (Cancel = '1') THEN Train_state <= Cancl;
        ELSE Train_state <= waiting1;
        END IF;

    WHEN waiting2 =>

        Ticket <= '0';
        Change <= "0000";

        IF  (RM1 = '1')     THEN Train_state <= S4;
        ELSIF (RM2 = '1')   THEN Train_state <= S5;
        ELSIF (RM5 = '1')   THEN Train_state <= S6;
        ELSIF   (Money_sum >= 4) THEN train_state <= Mid_Ticket;
        ELSIF (Cancel = '1') THEN Train_state <= Cancl;
        ELSE Train_state <= waiting2;
        END IF;

    WHEN waiting3 =>

        Ticket <= '0';
        Change <= "0000";

        IF  (RM1 = '1')     THEN Train_state <= S7;
        ELSIF (RM2 = '1')   THEN Train_state <= S8;
        ELSIF (RM5 = '1')   THEN Train_state <= S9;
        ELSIF   (Money_sum >= 6) THEN train_state <= Shah_Ticket;
        ELSIF (Cancel = '1') THEN Train_state <= Cancl;
        END IF;

    WHEN S1 =>

        IF (RM1 <= '1' AND RM2 <= '0' AND RM5 <= '0') THEN
        Ticket <= '0';
        Change <= "0000";
        Money_sum <= Money_sum + 1;
        ELSE    Train_state <= waiting1;
        END IF;

    WHEN S2 =>

        IF (RM1 <= '1' AND RM2 <= '1' AND RM5 <= '0') THEN
        Ticket <= '1';
        Change <= "0000";
        Money_sum <= Money_sum + 2;
        ELSE    Train_state <= waiting1;
        END IF;

    WHEN S3 =>

        IF (RM1 <= '0' AND RM2 <= '0' AND RM5 <= '1') THEN
        Ticket <= '1';
        Change <= "0001";
        Money_sum <= Money_sum + 5;
        ELSE    Train_state <= waiting1;
        END IF;

    WHEN S4 =>

        IF (RM1 <= '1' AND RM2 <= '0' AND RM5 <= '0') THEN
        Ticket <= '0';
        Change <= "0000";
        Money_sum <= Money_sum + 1;
        ELSE    Train_state <= waiting2;
        END IF;

    WHEN S5 =>

        IF (RM1 <= '0' AND RM2 <= '1' AND RM5 <= '0') THEN
        Ticket <= '0';
        Change <= "0000";
        Money_sum <= Money_sum + 2;
       ELSE Train_state <= waiting2;
        END IF;

    WHEN S6 =>

        IF (RM1 <= '0' AND RM2 <= '0' AND RM5 <= '1') THEN
        Ticket <= '0';
        Change <= "0001";
        Money_sum <= Money_sum + 5;
        ELSE    Train_state <= waiting2;
        END IF;

    WHEN S7 =>

        IF (RM1 <= '1' AND RM2 <= '0' AND RM5 <= '0') THEN
        Ticket <= '0';
        Change <= "0000";
        Money_sum <= Money_sum + 1;
        ELSE    Train_state <= waiting3;
        END IF;

    WHEN S8 =>

        IF (RM1 <= '0' AND RM2 <= '1' AND RM5 <= '0') THEN
        Ticket <= '0';
        Change <= "0000";
        Money_sum <= Money_sum + 2;
        ELSE    Train_state <= waiting3;
        END IF;

    WHEN S9 =>

        IF (RM1 <= '0' AND RM2 <= '0' AND RM5 <= '1') THEN
        Ticket <= '0';
        Change <= "0000";
        Money_sum <= Money_sum + 5;
        ELSE    Train_state <= waiting3;
        END IF;

    WHEN KL_Ticket =>

        Ticket <= '1';
        Change <= Money_sum - 2;
        Train_state <= waiting1;

    WHEN Mid_Ticket =>


        Ticket <= '1';
        Change <= Money_sum - 4;
        Train_state <= waiting2;


    WHEN Shah_Ticket =>


        Ticket <= '1';
       Change <= Money_sum - 6;
        Train_state <= waiting3;


    WHEN Cancl =>

        IF (Cancel <= '1') THEN
        Retrn <= Money_sum;
        ELSE    Train_state <= S0;

        END IF;
    END CASE;
END PROCESS;        

end Behavioral;
```

------------------------------simulation----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
 use ieee.numeric_std.all;  
 use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

 ENTITY trainticket_machine_tb IS
 END trainticket_machine_tb;

 ARCHITECTURE behavior OF trainticket_machine_tb IS 

 Signal Clock,Reset,Cancel,RM1,RM2,RM5,KL_station,Mid_station,Klang_station : std_logic := '0';
Signal Ticket : std_logic ;
signal Change,Retrn,Money_sum : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
 constant Clock_period : time := 10 ns;

 BEGIN

 uut: entity work.trainticket_machine PORT MAP (
      Clock => Clock,
      Reset => Reset,
      Cancel => Cancel,
      RM1 => RM1,
      RM2 => RM2,
      RM5 => RM5,
      KL_station => KL_station,
      Mid_station => Mid_station,
      Klang_station => Klang_station,
  Ticket => Ticket,
      Change => Change,
      Retrn => Retrn,
      Money_sum => Money_sum
    );

Clock_process :process
 begin
    Clock <= '0';
    wait for Clock_period/2;
    Clock <= '1';
    wait for Clock_period/2;
 end process;

 -- Stimulus process
 stim_proc: process
 begin      

    wait for Clock_period*2;
    Reset <= '1';
    wait for Clock_period;
    Reset <= '0';
    wait for Clock_period;
    Cancel <= '1';
    wait for Clock_period;
    Cancel <= '0';
    wait for Clock_period;
    KL_station <= '1';
    wait for Clock_period;
    KL_station <= '0';
    wait for Clock_period;
    Mid_station <= '1';
    wait for Clock_period;
    Mid_station <= '0';
    wait for Clock_period;
    Klang_station <= '1';
    wait for Clock_period;
    Klang_station <= '0';
    wait for Clock_period;
    RM1 <= '1';
    wait for Clock_period;
    RM1 <= '0';
    wait for Clock_period;
    RM2 <= '1';
    wait for Clock_period;
    RM2 <= '0';
    wait for Clock_period;
    RM5 <= '1';
    wait for Clock_period;
    RM5 <= '0';
    wait for Clock_period;
  wait;
  end process;

 END;
```

Comment: Precisely what do you expect?  Precisely what happens in the simulation (post waveforms - if you can't add them directly upload them somewhere else and add the URLs to the question - somone with more rep will add them to your question for you). what does your testbench look like?

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to add my simulation here.

Comment: Is your simulation not just some more VHDL code?

Comment: I add my simulation code

Comment: OK, now can you describe what you see (or post waveforms) and say what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the first problem you describe: since you are seeing only 'U's, maybe your outputs were never assigned any value. Did you remember to force `Reset` to `'1'` in the beginning of the simulation?

Now let's take a look at the state machine logic itself, which has many problems. First thing: you should differentiate between combinational logic and registered state. By state I mean values that must be kept in registers of flip-flops, between the clock transitions.

This is important because for each process you will have to decide whether it is combinational or registered. If the process is registered, it must be sensitive to your clock. If the process is combinational, it cannot have any statements that woud imply keeping state information.

So the first suggestion is to go through your code, and decide the nature of each process you have. You may have to create a few more processes, it's ok. From your code, it looks like the signal `money_sum` is state information, and therefore it should be updated on the rising edge of clock.

The second suggestion is: if you have an output that depends only on the current state (maybe your signal `ticket`), you need to assign a value to this signal on every condition of your case statement. Try removing the line `Ticket <= '0';` from your first process and see what happens.

Third, please use more descriptive names for your states and signals, it is really hard to understand what is going on from names like S0, S1, S2, RM1, RM2, and RM5.

Finally, it would be really helpful to have some assertions in your testbench code. For instance, after every `wait for Clock_period;`, you could check your outputs to make sure they match what you expected:

```
Reset <= '1';
wait for Clock_period;
assert ticket = '0' report "Wrong value for 'ticket' after reset";
assert change = "0000" report "Wrong value for 'change' after reset";
assert retrn = "0000" report "Wrong value for 'retrn' after reset";
assert money_sum = "0000" report "Wrong value for 'money_sum' after reset";
```

Comment: Thanks.I already add output under reset, simulation better than before but I am not see any output appear. It is my code correct to make all output appear like change,return,money_sum and ticket?

Comment: Now you will have a problem because you are assigning to some of the signals from two different processes. I'd recommend that you go back to what you had and drive only the signal `p_state` on the first process. What I really meant is that you should change your simulation (not you model VHDL code) so that at the beginning of the simulation you ensure that `Reset` gets a `1`. How do you force values on your simulation?